# How to include interactive input in script to be run from the command line

Tags: r

I am trying to write an interactive R script. For example:

try.R:

```
print("Entr some numbers. >",quote=F)
a = scan(what=double(0))
print a
q()
```

Now, if I run it on the command line as

```
$ R --no-save < try.R
```

It tries to get the stdin from try.R, giving the following error:

```
> print("Entr some numbers. >",quote=F)
[1] Entr some numbers. >
> a = scan(what=double(0))
1: print a
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  scan() expected 'a real', got 'print'
Execution halted
```

I tried a few other methods but they all give errors. For example:

```
$ R CMD BATCH try.R 
$ Rscript try.R
```

So how do I write an R script that works from the *nix shell command line, and can take in interactive input from the user?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this:

```
cat("What's your name? ")
x <- readLines(file("stdin"),1)
print(x)
```

Hopefully some variant of that works for you.

Comment: My bad, sorry. I happened to have used `readLines()` without a file argument, defaulting to stdin, at the same time -- see r-help as of this morning.

Comment: @Dirk, apparently `file("stdin")` and `stdin()` can refer to different things in different situations.  See `?file` and `?stdin`.

Comment: Dirk, this works fine in my CentOS machine but doesn't work in my Windows R. Is there a way to make it work in Windows as well?

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me on Windows with RStudio 0.98.945 and R version 3.1.1 was:

```
    cat("What's your name? ")
    x <- readLines(con=stdin(),1)
    print(x)
```

Comment: `stdin()` behaves differently when called from a GUI or from inside a command-line script (see `?stdin`). This question is about the latter.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Joshua Ulrich is fine for Linux, but hangs under macOS and needs to be terminated using Ctrl-D.

This is a work-around for both Linux and macOS:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

print(system("read -p 'Prompt: ' input; echo $input", intern = TRUE))
```

Comment: I can confirm that `readLines` works as expected on macOS. The issue is simply that `cat` without a trailing newline doesn’t reliably flush and thus there’s no prompt — manually flushing helps (but in my testing even this isn’t actually necessary in non-interactive scripts). It’s definitely *not* necessary (and not portable!) to call external tools.